# Angular speed around a star for different observers

Tags: general-relativity, angular-velocity

If we consider an observer orbiting an object with the standard Schwarzschild metric (at a fixed radius and in the equatorial plane), is the angular velocity $\frac{d\phi}{dt}$ observed by an observer at infinity the same as the angular velocity observed by the observer actually orbiting the black hole?

From my preliminary calculation:

$$\frac{d \phi}{dt}=\frac{d\phi}{d\tau} \frac{d\tau}{dt}=\frac{d\phi}{d\tau}$$

since $\frac{d\tau}{dt}=1$ for an observer at infinity.

Have I got something wrong here because this seems instinctively wrong?

Comment: It is wrong indeed. Try to understand [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/761407) answer.